# JavaScript How to get values from an array of objects into array of arrays so that each sub-array groups values from like keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects based on user input, for example:

```
const sortedByDate = [
  { Date: '2020-05-03', Genre: 'History', PageViews: '34' },
  { Date: '2010-01-16', Genre: 'History', PageViews: '10' },
  { Date: '1975-04-23', Genre: 'Literature', PageViews: '27' },
  { Date: '1997-10-14', Genre: 'History', PageViews: '3' },
  { Date: '1990-08-22', Genre: 'Literature', PageViews: '42' },
  { Date: '2001-06-13', Genre: 'Literature', PageViews: '64' }
]
```

How can I get the PageView values into an array of arrays such that each sub-array represents one Genre?  For example:

```
const chartData = [
  [ 34, 10, 3 ],  // These are the PageView values from the Genre 'History'
 [ 27, 42, 64 ]  // These are the PageView values from the Genre 'Literature'
]
```

The sortedByDate array above will have an arbitrary number of elements based on user input, and the chartData array needs to have an arbitrary number of sub-arrays based on the number of "Genres"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output can be achieved by using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and `Object.values`

```js
const sortedByDate = [
  { Date: '2020-05-03', Genre: 'History', PageViews: '34' },
  { Date: '2010-01-16', Genre: 'History', PageViews: '10' },
  { Date: '1975-04-23', Genre: 'Literature', PageViews: '27' },
  { Date: '1997-10-14', Genre: 'History', PageViews: '3' },
  { Date: '1990-08-22', Genre: 'Literature', PageViews: '42' },
  { Date: '2001-06-13', Genre: 'Literature', PageViews: '64' }
]

const getFormattedData = (data) => {
  const finalRes = data.reduce((res, {
    Genre,
    PageViews
  }) => {
    if (res[Genre]) {
      res[Genre].push(PageViews)
    } else {
      res[Genre] = [PageViews]
    }
    return res;
  }, {});

  return Object.values(finalRes);
}

console.log(getFormattedData(sortedByDate))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the array of objects to an object of arrays using the `Genre` property as the key. Convert the object to an array using `Object.values()`:

```js
const sortedByDate = [{"Date":"2020-05-03","Genre":"History","PageViews":"34"},{"Date":"2010-01-16","Genre":"History","PageViews":"10"},{"Date":"1975-04-23","Genre":"Literature","PageViews":"27"},{"Date":"1997-10-14","Genre":"History","PageViews":"3"},{"Date":"1990-08-22","Genre":"Literature","PageViews":"42"},{"Date":"2001-06-13","Genre":"Literature","PageViews":"64"}]

const fn = (data) => Object.values( // convert to an array of arrays
    data.reduce((r, { Genre, PageViews }) => {
      r[Genre] = r[Genre] || [] // create key by Genre if doesn't exist
      r[Genre].push(PageViews) // push to Genre key array

      return r;
    }, {})
  );

const result = fn(sortedByDate)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```